# How is the plus number on top of Google+ pages calculated?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-1, google-plus-pages

I know it is not *only* the number of followers.

But it is somehow related with +1s on page's posts, page's followers and page's +1s.

Also sometimes I note that the count decreases, not sure if it is related to the bug mentioned in [this article](http://marketingland.com/googleplus-1-numbers-decreasing-33233).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the answer by @Fogest was not acceptable for me, I tried to post an answer myself, but still I would like to get a more accurate answer with official references.

### Some facts about +1 count on Google+ pages

Google mentions [here](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1713819?hl=en) that any +1's on your ads will increment the count on your page and vice versa.

It seems +1's of the Google+ page is similar to the count of [+1 button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/) on the linked page/homepage. any +1 on the page also counts as a +1 for the linked homepage.

Google posted this on their [blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/12/google-few-big-improvements-before-new.html):

> We’ll now show an aggregated count of users that have engaged with your page, either by +1’ing it or by adding it to a circle. This way, both you and your page’s visitors can get an at-a-glance summary of who is interacting with your page.

According to the above, the +1 count should include:

- +1′s of the Google+ page
- Followers of the Google+ page (number of people who have the page in their circles)

Also according to my personal experience the +1's on the posts of the Google+ page also adds to the to Google+ page's +1's, but I couldn't find any official reference for that.

Answer (score -2):

It is the number of people who have `+1'ed` the page or website associated.

Comment: It is apparently also associated with +1'ing posts and also page followers, also clearly following a page is not same as +1'ing it.

Comment: There is a +1 button to the right of the follow button. The button also displays the number of people who +1'ed it.